# how to fix php page keeps on loading?

Tags: php, css, mysql

I am creating a webapp for my company and one of my PHP pages keeps on 
loading when I add another header.php into it, but another page is loading fine if I add this header.

my code: this section is added to the below page (view_enquiry.php)

head.php:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">

      <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="author" content="">
          <!-- Favicon icon -->
          <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="images/logo.png">
           <?php
                   include('connect.php');
                   $sql_head_title = "select * from manage_website"; 
                   $result_head_title = $conn->query($sql_head_title);
                   $row_head_title = mysqli_fetch_array($result_head_title);
                   ?>
          <title><?php echo $row_head_title['title'];?></title>

          <link href="css/lib/chartist/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/lib/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <link href="css/lib/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
          <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
          <link href="css/lib/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- Custom CSS -->
          <link href="css/helper.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/snackbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="css/modal.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
          <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:** -->
          <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
          <script src="https:**oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
      <![endif]-->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/lib/html5-editor/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" />
       <link href="css/lib/calendar2/semantic.ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link href="css/lib/calendar2/pignose.calendar.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>

      <body class="fix-header fix-sidebar">
          <!-- Preloader - style you can find in spinners.css -->
          <div class="preloader">
              <svg class="circular" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
            <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" /> </svg>
          </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

this is my page and this page keeps on loading (view_enquiry.php)

```
        <?php include('head.php');?>
        <?php include('header.php');?>
        <?php include('sidebar.php');?>

        <?php
            include ('connect.php');
        ?>

        <div class="content-wrapper" style="padding-top: 48px;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="status" style="color:red;position: relative;top:215px;positin: relative;left:565px;position:absolute;">
                    <h4>Status Updated Successfully</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="row" col-sm color: #031aaf" style="padding-top: 12px;">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <h3 style="color: #828282"><b>Enquiry Details</b></h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <form action="" method="get" " >
                            <input  name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search(Name/number)" size="20px">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" value="search" class="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-5" style="text-align: left;">
                        <form action="between.php" method="GET" >
                            <input type="date" name="from" required> To
                            <input type="date" name="to" required>
                            <button type="submit" class="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <b><p style="text-align:right; color: #828282" > Yesterday's Enquiry Count :
                    <?php
                        $v="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM task WHERE (`date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)AND completed=0" ;
                        $s=mysqli_query($conn,$v);
                        $w=mysqli_fetch_assoc($s);
                        echo $w['COUNT(id)'] ; 
                    ?>
                </b>
                <br><br>
                <table border="1px;"  style="margin-top:-11px;color: #333333" bgcolor="#fcb983" >
                    <tr style="color: black">
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Address</th>
                        <th>Enquiry Date</th>
                        <th>Category/Work</th>
                        <th>Followup Date</th>
                        <th>Mobile</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        <th>Postponed To</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                        <th>Complete</th>
                    </tr>
                    <?php 
                        if(@$_GET['search'] && @$_GET['search']!=''){
                            $query=$_GET['search'];
                            $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
                            $vari = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM task WHERE completed=0 AND ((`task_name` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`mobile` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`address` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`work` LIKE '%".$query."%') OR (`command` LIKE '%".$query."%'))") or die(mysqli_error($con));
                                            //$vari="SELECT * FROM task WHERE completed=0 AND (task_name='$s' OR mobile='$s')";
                                        }
                                    else{
                                            $vari = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM task WHERE (`date` = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND completed=0")  or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                                            //$vari="SELECT * FROM task WHERE completed=0";
                                        }
                                            //$variable=mysqli_query($con,$vari);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($vari)){ 
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["task_name"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["address"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($row["date"])); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["work"];?></td>
                        <td><?php echo date('D - d-m-Y',strtotime($row["todo"])); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["mobile"] ;?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row["command"];?></td>
                        <td><a href='postponed.php?postpo=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'><center><span class="fa fa-share"></span></center></a></td>
                        <td><a href='enqedit.php?edit=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>'><center><span class="fa fa-pencil"></span></center></a></td>
                        <td><a href='enqdelete.php?delete=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>' onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');"><center><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></center></a></td>
                        <td><a href="bill.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>"><center><span class="fa fa-check-square"></span></center></a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>    
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Please help me this details

Comment: remove </body></html> into head.php and add into footer file.

Comment: You include connect.php twice? Your query is wide open for injection. You should check this. I think it would help you to split the html from the php and first gather data and then think where to put it. I’m not sure what’s causing your issue. Tidying it up will Most likely solve it